# How to send XML data back to the browser using nodejs and express

Tags: jquery, xml, node.js, express

I"m trying to send back an XML error message to the browser in my nodejs / express application but the XML data doesn't get sent.

```
var xmlFile = '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
xmlFile += '<StatusCode>ERROR</StatusCode>';
xmlFile += '<StatusSubject>ERROR</StatusSubject>';
xmlFile += '<StatusMessage>' + dataCheck.error + '</StatusMessage>';
security = null;
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
res.send(xmlFile);
```

Any idea why I don't get a response back? If I skip setting the content type I get a response but then my front-end jQuery tells me that the XML is not valid.

Comment: How are you determining that you aren't getting a response back? Are you getting a Connection Timed Out error?

Comment: The XML **isn't** valid.

Comment: What is not valid in the XML?

Comment: @Quentin: No, I don't get a timeout. The browser just doesn't get a response. I use the Chrome debug tools to check for responses and their just is none.

Comment: It is not valid to have multiple root elements in an XML document.

Comment: ARGH. Of course... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For all who are struggling with something similar:
Here is the valid XML that works:

```
            var xmlFile = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
            xmlFile += '<Status>';
            xmlFile += '<StatusCode>ERROR</StatusCode>';
            xmlFile += '<StatusSubject>ERROR</StatusSubject>';
            xmlFile += '<StatusMessage>' + dataCheck.error + '</StatusMessage>';
            xmlFile += '</Status>';
            res.send(xmlFile);
```